# Being called after leaving personal data on SO accidentally

Tags: discussion, personal-data

A couple of hours ago I've made a big mistake, I have left my personal data in my question.

[Cannot get content in proper place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024665/cannot-get-content-in-proper-place/31024809#31024809)

I have edited it out but its still visible in the revisions of the questions AND answer. So I asked what I should do on SO Meta. They said I should flag the answers and the question for moderator attention but I don't think they have seen it.

What can I do? I've tried to delete my question but SO won't let me because it has answers.

So someone thinks this could be a duplicate of the other question. Alright this is a bit different. I've done everything possible to get the question or the revisions of the edits removed and it seems like the moderators did not see the flags. **How can I get the flag approved and the revisions deleted?**

Comment: How is this a duplicate...

Comment: It details that you're not obligated to reply to anyone calling/contacting you about questions here.  Flagging the question may motivate a moderator to contact a developer to remove the PII from the revision history, but outside of that, I doubt there's much else you *should* be doing.  You'll have to wait until a moderator sees it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first issue is that you linked to a Fiddle instead of putting your code in the question.

Even when we delete revisions, we can't control what other sites do.  That's a good reason to not use Fiddles instead of code.

A fiddle should be supplemental; we should be able to see all the code in your question without clicking a link. A secondary benefit is that when we delete revisions, you don't have to worry about another site.

I've deleted your question pending revision deletion; since it doesn't meet our criteria (it doesn't include an MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example), of the issue you're having, I can't undelete it.  Once you edit it to include the necessary code; flag it for undeletion.

I've flagged your post as well as the answers that contained a forked version of your JSFiddle for revision deletion.  This is something only CMs can do, but it's in their queue. Your question will be undeleted when this happens.

Comment: Hello George, I already updated the fiddle so its not the old fiddle anymore. And THANK YOU SO MUCH. Im so glad you helped

Comment: Huh, i dont understand. It will be undeleted when? I edit the question?

Comment: It will get undeleted after you edit the question to meet minimal site standards, the CM's get done pruning the revision history, and a mod gets around to processing your flag to undelete.